# Non-algebraic flops

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I am looking at Exercise 84 on Kollár's *Exercises in the birational geometry of algebraic varieties* about non-algebraic flops:

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ be a general smooth quintic hypersurface. It is know that for every $d \geq 1$, $X$ contains a smooth rational curve $\mathbb{P}^1 \cong C_{d} \subset X$ of degree $d$ with normal bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus 2}$. Prove that the flop of $C_{d}$ exists if we work with compact complex manifolds. Denote the flop by $\phi_{d}: X \dashrightarrow X_{d}$ and let $H_d$ be the image of the hyperplane class. Compute the self intersection $(H_{d})^{3}$ and conclude that the $X_{d}$ are not homeomorphic to each other and not projective.

If I'm correct the intersection number $(H_{d})^{3} = 5 - 5d^3$ and the picard number $\rho(X_{d}) = 1$ so $X_{d}$ is not projective. However, I think the variety $X_{d}$ is constructed by first blowing up the curve $C_d$ with exceptional divisor $E \cong \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, and then contract the other negative extremal ray by the minimal model program. Doesn't this construction always give projective varieties? I feel like I messed up with something in this contradiction.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Actually, my computation shows that $(H_d)^3=5-d^3$.

Comment: Another comment: There is a misquote in Kollar's statement. In the original Clemens' paper, the degree of $C_d$ is something like a quadric polynomial dependent on $d$ (computed in Voisin's _Variations of Hodges structure of Calabi-Yau threefolds_, Chapter 4). It's not the case that for each degree there is such a rational curve, at least not from the Clemens' construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading some analytic theory on contractions, it turns out the point here is that the other fibre of the exceptional divisor $E$ is *not extremal*, so one cannot use the Minimal Model Program here. Instead one should use the following analytic contraction theorem of Nakano (Main Theorem, *On the Inverse of Monoidal Transformation*, Shigeo Nakano):

> Let $\tilde{X}$ be a complex analytic manifold of complex dimension $n \geq 3$ and $S$ an analytic submanifold of $\tilde{X}$ of codimension 1. Suppose that $S$ has a structure of an analytic fibre bundle over an analytic manifold $M$ with a projective $(r-1)$-space as the standard fibre and that $r > 1$. Denote $L_a$ the fibre over $a \in M$ in the bundle $S \rightarrow M$. Then, in order that there exists an $n$-dimensional analytic manifold $X$ containing $M$ and a holomorphic map $\pi: \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ in such a way that $(\tilde{X},\pi)$ is the monoidal transformation of $X$ with center $M$ and $S = \pi^{-1}(M)$, it is necessary and sufficient that the following conditions are satisfied:(1) for any $a \in M$, $\mathcal{O}(S)|_{L_a} \cong \mathcal{O}_{L_a}(-1)$; (2) each $L_a$ has a neighbourhood $V$ in $\tilde{X}$ such that $\mathcal{O}(K_V) = \mathcal{O}(S)^{k}$, where $k$ is a non-negative integer.

One can verify condition (1) by computing the normal bundle of $S$, and condition (2) from the fact that $X$ is smooth Calabi-Yau variety.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question. I was also puzzled by this for a while. Here is a proof of why the fiber $F_2$ of the other contraction is not an extremal curve.

Let $\tilde{X}$ denote the blowup of $X$ at one rational curve $C$ of degree $d$. The exceptional divisor $E\cong \mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$ has two rulings $F_1$ and $F_2$. $F_1$ is a fiber of $\tilde{X}\to X$ and $F_2$ is the fiber of the other contraction.

Since $X$ contains 2875 lines, one can take one of the lines $L$ disjoint from $C$. Now we have three curve classes $[L], [F_1]$ and $[F_2]$ for $\tilde{X}$. Since $H^4(X,\mathbb Z)$ has rank 1 (generated by $[L]$),  $H^4(\tilde{X},\mathbb Z)$ has rank 2 according to the [blowup formula for cohomology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394161/whats-the-cohomology-ring-structure-of-a-blow-up), so there has to be a relation between three classes.

We claim that
$$[F_2]=d[L]+[F_1]. \label{1}\tag{1}$$
This shows $[F_2]$ is indeed not extremal in the cone of curves.

It suffices to show the intersection number with all the surface classes on the both sides of equation coincide. The Picard group $\text{Pic}(\tilde{X})$ is generated by $E$ and the strict transform $\tilde{H}$ of a general hyperplane section $H$. A direct computation shows:

$$\tilde{H}\cdot L= 1, ~E\cdot L= 0,$$
$$\tilde{H}\cdot F_1= 0, ~E\cdot F_1= -1,$$
$$\tilde{H}\cdot F_2= d, ~E\cdot F_2= -1.$$

Therefore the equation $\eqref{1}$ is established.

(p.s., I still can't see homologically why the relation $\eqref{1}$ holds, i.e., how to find a 3-chain bounding the three curves.)